# Play continuous audio in background of app in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have made an android application in that i want to play a continuous audio in background.I have done successfully to start the audio,but when i stop the audio it starts again.My code is as below,Please suggest me any solution..
**code**

```
 public static void PlayMusic(Context context){

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.saturday);

 if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
       mediaPlayer.start();
       Toast.makeText(context,
         "soundPool.pause()",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

else {
       mediaPlayer.stop();
       Toast.makeText(context,
         "soundPool.pause()",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to play the sound

```
private void play(String uriString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

        if (uri != null) {
            // in order to play the ringtone, you need to create a new Ringtone
            // with RingtoneManager and pass it to a variable
            try {
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
                final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

and stop the played sound with -

```
if (mPlayer != null) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sets the player to be looping or non-looping.

```
 mediaPlayer.setlooping(true)
```